# Is this a way to show a modeless dialog from a dockable pane using WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, revit-api, revit

I'm building a Revit plugin. It consists of a dockable pane that (among other elements) has a button. I want to open a new, separate window when a user clicks this button.

At the moment, i create a new `Window`, but i don't know if that's the right way to go, because now i see two Revit icons on a task bar. I do not have experience as Revit user, i'm new to Revit development, so i'm not sure if this should be the case (two icons) and as silly as it sounds, i do not have admin rights to install random addins and get a feeling of expected user experience.

[image]

I create a `Window` using the following code:

```
ParametersMissingValueWindow parametersMissingValueWindow = new ParametersMissingValueWindow();
parametersMissingValueWindow.Show();
```

Based on the understanding of a dockable pane that i have, i think i do not want to create another dockable pane, but just a simple modeless dialog. I wasn't able to find any examples using WPF. Hence, any information whether this is the way to go or help on how to achieve this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var MyWindow = new MyWindow();
HwndSource hwndSource = HwndSource.FromHwnd(UIApplication.MainWindowHandle);
Window wnd = hwndSource.RootVisual as Window;
if (wnd != null)
{
    MyWindow.Owner = wnd;
    //MyWindow.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    MyWindow.Show();
}
```

It's not necessary to assign a value to `ShowInTaskbar` property, but it actually achieves what i wanted to do from the beginning (have only one program open in taskbar), so i left it as part of the solution, but commentted out.

Big thanks to Jeremy Tammik for pointing out the `parent` property.

Answer (score 1):

The `Show` method takes an optional parent window argument. Specify the Revit main window as the parent window, and your modeless dialogue will be recognised as belonging to the running Revit process. It is accessible from the [`MainWindowHandle` property](https://apidocs.co/apps/revit/2019/a18b37eb-cfa9-198c-bb54-65ca60dd72fa.htm).

Comment: It sounds exactly like a thing i need! I'm trying to find a way to apply it to my WPF plugin, since a `Show` you mentioned has an optional parent argument for `Form` elements, which don't exist in WPF and i'm not sure what their WPF equivalent is. If you happen to know, please edit your answer.

Comment: Also, why do both `UIApplication.MainWindowHandle` and `UIControlledApplication.MainWindowHandle` return `MainWindowHandle`? Is it the same handle, does it matter where i retrieve it from?

Comment: It is the same handle and does not matter which of them you use. I don't know WPF.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WPF to setup a window to use in revit.

```
MyWPF menu = new menu();
System.Windows.Window wind = new System.Windows.Window();
wind.ShowDialog();    //--> the window shows up and make stuff for revit
```

if you need the menu to be a dockable one check this [source](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/05/a-simpler-dockable-panel-sample.html).

Perhaps is not up to date and you will need to adapt the code to the new api.

Comment: Won't 2nd and 3rd line of code present modal dialog? I was wondering how to present modeless dialog.

Comment: My bad, you are right, to show a modeless dialog you can check this example: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Modeless-Window-in-WPF-492cb24f
I didn't tested on revit but it should work.